# Simple PHP for loop going infinite

Tags: php, infinite-loop

I am new to PHP programming but this seems really straight forward. However every time I run this I get stuck in an infinite loop. `$facility` is an array, in my current tests `size=2`. Any help would be appreciated. It appears as though the issue is not necessarily an infinite loop, the webpage got stuck in a constantly loading state until I kill the process so I assumed infinite loop.

```
$facility = $_POST['facility'];

$whereClause = 'WHERE c.residentId = r.residentId AND c.sid = s.id AND p.sid = s.id AND c.createdAt BETWEEN p.effectiveStart AND p.effectiveEnd';

if ($facility[0] !== "ALL") {
  $whereClause = $whereClause.' AND s.facilityAbbr = "'.$facility[0].'"';

  $size = sizeof($facility);
  for($i = 1; $i< $size; $i++)
  {
    $whereClause = $whereClause.' OR c.facilityAbbr = "'.$facility[$i].'"';
  } 
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using `"... WHERE c.facilityAbbr IN ('".implode("','",$facility[$i])."')"`? (assuming correct escaping/handling/would totally be better as a prepared query)

Comment: Is this the exact code you're running? I don't see any way this loop would be infinite.

Comment: Definitely is not an infinite loop. Also, arrays start with `0`

Comment: [sizeof](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sizeof.php) is just  an alias of [count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) so you can use it instead

Comment: If i comment out the body of the loop it no longer causes problems. I will be trying @NiettheDarkAbsol suggestion for a better prepared query.

Comment: prefer the count() function instead of sizeOf() as sizeOf() is only an alias of count() and does not mean the same in many other languages based on C (avoid ambiguity).

Comment: What is your issue that commenting out a body solves?

Comment: is `$whereClause`  defined before the loop.  otherwise your accessing an undefined variable by concatenation.  Also id do `$whereClause .= '` instead of  `$whereClause = $whereClause . '`

Comment: You'll have to provide more code than what you currently have in here.

Comment: Updated to show the entire code block that is relevant

Comment: Could you show us what `$facility` and your expected/given result looks like. Still nothing here say infinite loop potential

Comment: It might be because one of your `$facility` elements contain special characters like double quotes (`"`) which would break your code. In that case try doing a prepared statement. Also as @nerdlyist mentioned, provide a dump of what `$facility` holds.

Comment: $facility contains:  array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "DC"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "MPL"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to make sure your string variable is initialized before concatenating to it.

```
$whereClause = '';
$size = sizeof($facility);
for($i = 1; $i<$size; $i++) {
    $whereClause .= ' OR c.facilityAbbr = "'.$facility[$i].'"';
}
```

As I mentioned int he comments, how to shorten the line, I'll post it here so it makes a bit more sense.

Also, note the only way this is an infinate loop is if `$facility` is an array with infinite items in it, which is doubtful.  You may want to turn on error reporting, by putting this somewhere before that code.

```
  ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

You could also use a Foreach loop, which is more appropriate IMO, and less code.

```
$whereClause = '';
foreach( $facility as $item ){
   $whereClause .= ' OR c.facilityAbbr = "'.$item.'"';
}
```